# How to move location of trigger's script in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

we have to move the location of the trigger's script. What is the cleartool command to change that location?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-define an existing trigger type with [**`mktrtype`**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm), using the -replace option.

You need to use the same command you used to define the trigger in the first place, but replacing the location with the new path for `-execunix` and/or `-execwin`.

```
-rep/lace
```

> Replaces the existing definition of type-name with a new one.
>   If you do not include options from the existing definition, their values are replaced with the defaults.

Comment: Thank you. However it seems that I have to provide options even-though I use "-replace", which means I have to change each trigger separately! Annoying ClearCase.

Comment: @VonC, Need your help please on this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074936/change-trigger-in-clear-case-remote-client