# Change trigger in Clear Case Remote Client

Tags: version-control, clearcase

In `Clear Case Remote Client`, we use to create new VOB based on VOB selection rule. I checked out a couple of files, but `when trying to checkin`, I obtain following error -

> CRVAP0087E CCRC command 'checkin' failed:
>
> /bin/sh: /vob/cspecs/triggers/scripts/checkin.sh: No such file or
> directory ClearCase CM Server: Warning: Trigger "**checkin_SomeOtherBranch**" has
> refused to let checkin proceed.

Please note, as per my vob selection rule, remote client should trigger, **checkin_MyBranch** for checkin.

As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890372/how-to-move-location-of-triggers-script-in-clearcase), we can redefine existing trigger with **mktrtype**, Since command line is not available in **CCRC**. Couldn't try this command to resolve my issue.

Have you come across this situation, I am not precisely clear what is the purpose of trigger in CCRC.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Was it on the server side?

Comment: @VonC To get the vob, I had used Build Machine specs, whose vob rule contained backslash `\MyApplication\version-x.x.xx` However Remote Client rules contained, `/vob/MyApplication/version-x.xx.xx`. This use to trigger wrong trigger in clearcase while checkin.

Comment: Ok, so it was on the client side, with your ccweb view configured with the wrong rules then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be best debug on the CCRC server side (which has full access to all the base ClearCase commands, like `mktrtype`), like this trigger example for [limiting the `delete` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146314).
You wouldn't be able to modify it from a client (ie from a CCRC web view)

Check however that, on the CCRC server, the path `/vob/cspecs/triggers/scripts/checkin.sh` is there (and the vob `cspecs` is mounted). It should be available though, or you would have error message about "interactive session" as well (see "[Non-interactive triggers fail with warning about interactivity using CCRC or CCWeb](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266044)")
This looks like a custom trigger, put in place on the ClearCase server side. I don't know what its purpose would be.

Comment: Server seems to be fine, because I encounter error while checkin only on this machine. Other team members, are able to check with their IDs.  To get source code, we enter VOB rule only. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @autrevo is there any difference between your ccweb view selection/loading rules and the ones on the colleague's ccrc web view? Do you have set your primary group through the client? Do you see the same error message for any files? Did you already checked in successfully a file?

Comment: There is no difference, in my vob rules and others.

Comment: @autrevo is the parent directory checked out? Did you first refresh your view (Update Resource)? What about the other questions I previously asked? (primary group?, any file? already checked in once?)